# Select content nodes and pass the selected ones to a controller of a custom module

Tags: views, 8

I am developing a module and I have cloned the content view (/ admin / content /) that comes by default in drupal 8, what I need is to select each one of the nodes (checkboxes) and execute an event with a button.

So far, in the .routing.yml file of my module I have added and I can see the view that shows all the contents, but it comes with the action combo and a button to apply the action to the selected elements.

How can I just show a button that has another text and that at the moment of clicking, I pass the selected nodes to a controller that has another route configured?

[image: example]

Thanks.

Comment: You'd either have to submit a form, or use javascript to append the IDs of the selected items to the URL that is visited when you click the button. You would be better off writing your own bulk operation, though, then you can stay within existing core functionality

Comment: Hey @Clive do you mean using the Views Bulk Operations module, or implement a Plugin with an action directly?